# matplotlib set own axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphic

I have points 

`x = [1000,  15000, 28000, 70000, 850000]
y = [10000, 20000, 30000, 10000, 50000]`

and I get this graphic [image]

How can I set  my own values on x axis?

Example : 1000, 15000, 28000, 70000, 850000

I Wanna get like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you want them spaced equally that way then?

Comment: I want not linear change values on x axis

Comment: Ok, see my answer below, it should do what you want :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your graphic, you actually want the points to be spaced equally in `x` and then to set the equally spaced ticks as your custom `x` array.

The code below will plot them equally (it actually plots them at [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]). It then places ticks at the positions (0, 1, 2, 3,...) with the values given by `x` using the `plt.xticks` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1000,  15000, 28000, 70000, 850000]
y = [10000, 20000, 30000, 10000, 50000]

x_plot = range(len(y))

plt.plot(x_plot, y)

plt.xticks(x_plot, x)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]